# Using IComparable

Tags: c#, icomparable

So I'm drawing a blank on this error.
Failed to compare two elements in the array. 
The Array.Sort(patient); is where the error is accruing. I do have a IComparable interface, and a class file with the following code: Trying to sort by patient ID number

```
class Patient : IComparable
{
    private int patientID;
    private string patientName;
    private int patientAge;
    private decimal amount;

    public int PatientId { get; set; }

    public string PatientName { get; set; }

    public int PatientAge { get; set; }

    public decimal PatientAmount { get; set; }


    int IComparable.CompareTo(Object o)
    {
        int value;
        Patient temp = (Patient)o;
        if (this.PatientId > temp.PatientId)
            value = 1;
        else if (this.PatientId < temp.PatientId)
            value = -1;
        else
            value = 0;
        return value;
    }
}
```

and this is what's in my main method. Didn't add the Display() cause nothing added to it now, why it's commented out

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int numOfPatients =2 ;

        Patient[] patient = new Patient[numOfPatients];
        for (int x = 0; x < numOfPatients; x++)
        {


            int intvalue;
            decimal dollarValue;
            patient[x] = new Patient();

            Console.Write("Patient {0}: ", (x + 1));
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the Patients ID: ");
            bool isNum = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out intvalue);
            if (isNum)
            {
                patient[x].PatientId = intvalue;

            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Patient ID was invalid. ID needs to be numbers");
                Console.WriteLine("Enter the Patients ID: ");
                int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out intvalue);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Enter the Patients Name: ");
            patient[x].PatientName = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Enter the Patients Age: ");
            bool isAge = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out intvalue);
            if (isAge)
            {
                patient[x].PatientAge = intvalue;

            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Patient Age was invalid. Age needs to be numbers");
                Console.WriteLine("Enter the Patients Age: ");
                int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out intvalue);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Enter the Patients Amount Due: ");
            bool isAmount = Decimal.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out dollarValue);
            if (isAmount)
            {
                patient[x].PatientAmount = dollarValue;

            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Patient amount Due was invalid. Amount needs to be a numbers");
                Console.WriteLine("Enter the Patients Amount Due: ");
                int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out intvalue);
            }


        }
        Array.Sort(patient);
        Console.WriteLine("Patients in order with Amounts Owed are: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < patient.Length; ++i) ;
        //Display(patient[i], numOfPatients);
```

Comment: And what error are you getting? That doesn't sound like a standard .NET exception

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Failed to compare two elements in the array. Is what the error that coming up is

Comment: You don't handle NULL and objects not of your class in the compare method.

Comment: It does sound like it's comparing `null` to me. I thought it might have been in the implementation of IComparable (if a.CompareTo(b) != b.CompareTo(a) in debug it will throw), but it looks fine.

Comment: See if there in an `InnerException` that gives you more detail.  Only hole I can see is a possible `NullReferenceException`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things come to mind:

a) Why not implement `IComparable<Patient>`?

b) Why re-implement `int.CompareTo(int)`? Your implementation of IComparable could just return `this.PatientID.CompareTo(other.PatientID)`.

c) Are you *sure* the array is full when you're sorting it? I'm not sure what would happen if it contains `null`.

Comment: thanks I did the `IComparable<Patient>` way and had to use  `set{accessor-body}` And the error stopped

Answer (score 1):

I would just write

```
return this.PatientId.CompareTo(temp.PatientId)
```

inside the overriden CompareTo method the class. No need to use equality symbols. This will do the int compare for you and return the correct value.

I also suggest that you just use some implementation of the IList class, and then you can use LinQ statements. Using this will prevent there ever being a null value in the "array"

Answer (score 0):

It looks like if Array.Sort is passed with a typed array would call the `Array.Sort<T>(T[])` overload. According to the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.sort%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), this overload uses the `IComparable<T>` interface to compare objects. So it looks like you have two choices:

1. You can implement `IComparable<T>` instead of `IComparable` (better).
2. You could cast your array to `Array` to call the `Array.Sort(Array)` overload which uses the `IComparable` interface (worse).